# String processing and memory management in C++

Tags: c++

I have certain string processing to do , the approach I am using is in following sample -

```
Void ProcessObjects(int nObject)
{
    std::string sInfostr;

    for(int i = 0;i<nObject;i++)
    {
      InfoObject Inf = new InfoObject; 
      GetInfoObject(&Inf);
      GetStoredInformation(Inf, std::string &sInfostr)
      delete Inf;           
    }
}


void GetStoredInformation(InfoObject Inf, std::string &sInfostr) 
{
    char tag[1000]; 

    GetInformation(&Inf);

    sprintf(tag, "name=%s",Inf.name);
    sInfostr += tag;        
    sprintf(tag, "name1=%s",Inf.name1);
    sInfostr += tag;
    sprintf(tag, "name2=%s",Inf.name2);
    sInfostr += tag;
    sprintf(tag, "name3=%s",Inf.name3);
    sInfostr += tag;
    sprintf(tag, "name4=%s",Inf.name4);
}
```

Now can I get some suggestion is it a good way to process string?
Will I code go in any trouble if "nObject" above 10,000?

Comment: Why aren't `GetInfObject()` and `GetStoredInformation()` methods of `InfoObject`?

Comment: Why not declare `name`, `name1`.... `name4` all as `std::string`?

Comment: "the approach I am using is in following sample". No it is not. This code is littered with syntax errors. Please post a working sample.

Comment: newing and deleting an object in the loop seems a bit unnecessary. You could just as well use an automatic object, possible hoisted out of the loop. - Also usage like `InfoObject Inf = GetInfoObject();` is simpler and probably also more efficient than what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use `std::istringstream` instead of the old C-ish `sprintf`:

```
void GetStoredInformation(InfoObject Inf, std::string &sInfostr) 
{
    GetInformation(&Inf);
    std::istringstream stream();
    stream << "name=" << Inf.name
           << "name1=" << Inf.name1
           << "name2=" << Inf.name2
           << "name3=" << Inf.name3
           << "name4=" << Inf.name4;
    sInfostr = stream.str();
}
```

> Will I code go in any trouble if "nObject" above 10,000?

Depends on your used hardware, from the C++ point of view it should not be a problem, unless your `InfoObject` is not extremely large.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very sketchy, and contains several syntax errors and probably a memory leak.

About your actual question, using `std::stringstream` is the recommended way to build strings. It would look like this:

```
std::stringstream buffer;
buffer << "name=" << Inf.name
    << "name1=" << Inf.name1; // etc.
```

You can access the contents of buffer as an `std::string` using `buffer.str()`.

Aside from being more elegant, this is probably also faster, because `std::stringstream` uses a smarter allocation-strategy than `operator +=` of `std::string`.

Comment: Are you sure.  The last time I measured (some time ago), the implementation of `std::ostringstream` I used ended up just doing `+=` on a `std::string`.  In this particular case (just appending strings), `std::string` would be simpler and more rapid.  (Use `ostringstream`, of course, if you have to convert anything.)

Comment: @James: To be honest, I am not sure, since I have not measured.

Answer (score 1):

If you declare `name`, `name1`.... `name4` all as `std::string`, then you would simply write:

```
sInfostr = "name  = " + Inf.name 
         + "name1 = " + Inf.name1 
         + "name2 = " + Inf.name2
         + "name3 = " + Inf.name3 
         + "name4 = " + Inf.name4;
```

which is much neater solution, as it is easier to read and maintain.

You can add member function called `ToString()` to `InfoObject` class as:

```
class InfoObject
{
  //...
  std::string ToString() const
  {
     return  = "name  = " + Inf.name 
             + "name1 = " + Inf.name1 
             + "name2 = " + Inf.name2
             + "name3 = " + Inf.name3 
             + "name4 = " + Inf.name4;
  }
};
```

Then `GetStoredInformation` would be just two lines:

```
void GetStoredInformation(InfoObject Inf, std::string &sInfostr) 
{
    GetInformation(&Inf);
    sInfostr = Inf.ToString();
}
```

Even better would be if you make `GetStoredInformation` a member function of `InfoObject`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `sprintf` at all. As you suspect, it is not safe. If any of the `Inf.name*` strings are longer than 1000 characters, you will corrupt the stack which can cause a crash or worse, a security breach via code injection.

Your format string is simple enough; the solution should be more like,

```
void GetStoredInformation(InfoObject Inf, std::string &sInfostr) 
{
    GetInformation(&Inf);
    sInfostr += "name=";// did you mean sInfostr = "name"?
    sInfostr += Inf.name;
    sInfostr += "name1=";
    sInfostr += Inf.name1;
    sInfostr += "name2=";
    sInfostr += Inf.name2;
    sInfostr += "name3=";
    sInfostr += Inf.name3;
    sInfostr += "name4=";
    sInfostr += Inf.name4;
}
```